# Validation is not working for dynamically added fields?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have **bootstrap modal box** button which contain the **dynamic added fields button**. The JavaScript is not working for the fields which appear when I click add more button.

Below is my code:

**index.php**

```
<a href="new_user_popup.php" style="color:white" target="_blank" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info new_entry_btn" style="margin-left:0%">
        New Entry
    </button>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#trigger').click(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            return false;
        })
    });

    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).find('.modal-dialog').css({width:'auto',
                                           height:'auto', 
                                           'max-height':'100%'
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="container">
    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <!-- Content will be loaded here from "remote.php" file -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**new_user_popup.php**

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-24">
    <div class="input_fields" style="color:black">
        <button class="add_field  btn " onclick="incrementValue()" style="margin-left: 443px;">Add</button>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="mytextt[]" hidden="" ></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add_field"); //Add button ID

        var wrapper_pre1         = $(".present_fields_1"); //Fields wrapper
        var x = 1; //initlal text box count

        $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();

            if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box incrementa

            $('<div style="margin-left:50%;"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="selectbasic" style="margin-left:-220px;">Type of work</label><div class="col-md-6"><select id="type_of_work[]" name="type_of_work[]" class="form-control" style="margin-left:17%;width:222%"><option value="Option one">Audit Report</option><option value="Option two">ITR filing</option><option value="Option three">VAT Filing</option><option value="Option four">Accounting</option><option value="Option five">Registration</option><option value="Option six">Certification</option><option value="Option seven">Others</option></select></div></div><div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic" style="margin-left:-29%">Status</label><div class="col-md-6"><select id="status11' + x + '" name="status[]" style="width:210%;margin-left:-1%;" class="form-control"><option value="Pending">Pending</option><option value="Work in process">Work in process</option><option value="Completed">Completed</option></select></div></div><div class="form-group row"><label for="example-date-input" class="col-2 col-form-label" style="margin-left:-15.5%;";">DATE</label><div class="col-8"><input class="form-control datepicker pick" id="datee' + x + '" name="date[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['date'] ?>" style="width:86%;margin-left:10.6%;margin-top:-10%;" type="text" readonly></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput" style="margin-left:-36%">Comment</label><div class="col-md-4"><input id="comments11' + x + '" name="comment[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" style="width:342%;margin-left:20%"></div></div></center><a href="#" class="remove_field" style="margin-left: 197px; margin-top: -40px;position:absolute"><img src="images/del24.png"></a></a></div>').insertBefore(add_button) //add input box        
                var newInput=$("#datee"+ x).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});

                newInput.datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
                $("#status11" + x).click(function () {
                    if ($("#status11" + x).val() == "Completed") {
                        $("#comments11" + x).attr("required", "required");
                    }
                    else
                        $("#comments11" + x).attr("required", false);
                });
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })

        $(wrapper_pre1).on("click",".remove_field_pre1", function(e) { //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please, can you check my answer and accept it if it solve your problem? thx

Comment: The javascript is not working inside add button fields@Peter.can u give me some other idea

Comment: Have you changed ALL .click part to the suggested? Could you edit your code based on my advice?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you sould use `on()` on dynamically added DOM elements.

```
$(add_button).on('click', function (e) {
```

Comment: The javascript is not working for the dynamically added fields.@Peter

Answer (score 0):

As mentionnd by Peter, you should use on() on dynamically added DOM element. I assume you need the JS to be executed on your (#status11 & #comments11) selectors?

```
$("#status11" + x).on('click', function () {
```

Instead of :

```
$("#status11" + x).click(function () {
```

Comment: i have updated my code but still the validation is not working@Lou

Comment: plase update your code in question with your updates

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your event listener on new fields with the `on` function, you just have to change up how it's written.

Instead of having a function like this:

```js
$('.my-field').on('click', function() {});
```

Use the parent element to watch for specific child elements like this:

```js
$('.parent-container').on('click', '.my-field', function() {});
```

Comment: i tried this method but it is not at all working the javascript.@Chris

Comment: Take a look at this example.  I'm not sure if it is going to solve your problem exactly, but it should show how you can get dynamic elements. http://jsbin.com/fodifarico/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

when you are loading html content with ajax in that .modal-content div you must use

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
 // do your .click which is interacting with the html in the dynamic loaded div 
});
```

instead of $(document).ready